# Unable to turn off logging in console in logback

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, slf4j, logback

I want the console logging to turn off and file logging to turn on. Is this possible in logback?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <!-- Send debug messages to System.out -->
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- By default, encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder -->
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>OFF</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- Send debug messages to a file at "c:/jcg.log" -->
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/home/dev-01/Documents/jcg.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>/home/dev-01/Documents/jcg-%i.log</FileNamePattern>
            <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
            <MaxIndex>10</MaxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>100MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>

    <!-- By default, the level of the root level is set to DEBUG -->
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I am open to use another logging libraries if this is not possible in logback.

Answer (score 3):

Delete the appender-ref STDOUT reference

```
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know logback but you might set logging level to OFF for the console logger.

Like this (removing STDOUT appender from `root` logger) :

```
<logger name="consoleLogger" level="OFF">
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>

<root level="INFO">
  <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

See : [Can I disable an appender in logback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913160/can-i-disable-an-appender-in-logback)

***EDIT*** : added XML sample

Comment: Based on my configuration I already set it as OFF, but it is still logging the exception that can occur.
Please see the filter in the STDOUT.

Comment: I meant level OFF on logger, not on filter.