# How to disable Crawler4J logger?

Tags: java, crawler4j

I am crawling using Crawler4J.

I don't want to print log messages.

But Crawler4J has a logger in it.

How can I disable logger inner Crawler4J lib?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crawler4J is using `slf4j` API and `logback` as implementation. There was an [issue](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/issues/50) about having the `logback.xml` file inside the build jar, and it was [fixed](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/pull/67).

Please make sure that you have the latest version and you don't have the file `logback.xml` inside the crawler4j jar.

You can disable the logging by providing your own `logback.xml` file with the level set to `OFF`  like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913160/can-i-disable-an-appender-in-logback).

Comment: See my answer below for an extended edit recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Crawler4J is using slf4j API and logback as implementation. There was an issue about having the logback.xml file inside the build jar, and it was fixed.

Please make sure that you have the latest version and you don't have the file logback.xml inside the crawler4j jar.

You can disable the logging by providing your own logback.xml file with the level set to OFF. This file should be placed in the src/main/resources directory of a maven project. This example is what is provided by default by slf4j but with the output turned off:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="OFF">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

(This is really an extended edit recommendation for Amr ElAdawy, but my edit correction was rejected)